# Card does not return Status Word when data to retrieve exceeds 256 bytes

Tags: smartcard, iso, apdu

I'm working with a card in **T=0** protocol:

- I send a command to the Card that request a response with data.
- The applet I use is expected to answer with data, **potentially more than 256 bytes**, so in the command Le is set to '00'
- Card first answers with `61 XX` where 'XX' is the count of bytes to read (from 1 to 256).
- Then I retrieve the data by sending a GET RESPONSE command:

  00 C0 00 00 XX

### Expectation:

Regarding ISO7816-3, I expected the Card to respond with:

```
Procedure byte | Data | SW1 SW2
```

And if `SW1 == 0x61`, I would send:

```
00 C0 00 00 SW2
```

And so on, until eventually I get `90 00`.

### Reality:

However, this is what I actually have (TPDU level):

```
> Command
< 61 00

> 00 C0 00 00 00
< C0 (procedure byte)
< Data (256)
No Status Word, no procedure byte (timeout)

> 00 C0 00 00 00
< C0 (procedure byte)
< Data (256)
No Status Word, no procedure byte (timeout)

[...]

> 00 C0 00 00 00
< 61 39 (status word)
```

I have to repeatedly send GET RESPONSE with P3=00 (256), read the 256 bytes and got no Status Word until the Card warns me that there is actually less than 256 bytes to read.

I can't found the part of the specification that allows the card to "skip" the status word, or how to deal with answers longer than 256 bytes. Any pointer ?

Comment: which card and reader you are using.

Comment: "If the value [of the procedure byte] is the value of INS, apart from the values '6X' and '9X', it is an ACK byte. **All remaining data
bytes** if any bytes remain, denoted Di to Dn, shall be transferred subsequently. **Then the interface device
shall wait for a character conveying a procedure byte.**"

Comment: No mention of SW1/SW2 in these successive transfers...

Comment: @vikky Neither card and reader are "official". I have a "dev" card and I am developing the reader's firmware.

Comment: @JimmyB It was my understanding that the remaining byte would be 256 since there is no way to know a priori how much the card have to send and that GET RESPONSE set PE = '00' means 256.  After I read 256 bytes, If I wait for a procedure byte I have a timeout. I have to re-send GET RESPONSE

Comment: "If I wait for a procedure byte I have a timeout" - Yes, from your question that's what I figured. So the spec does *not* say that you should expect SW1/SW2, but also it says you should wait for more data, which apparently does not work in your case.

Comment: @JimmyB I'm not sure to understand: you quoted 10.3.3 in 7816-3. Just above (10.3.2) it is stated that D1 to Dn are the nb of bytes coded by P3. So in my case, after transferring 256 bytes I would expect the card to "finish" the command by SW1 SW2. I would end-up in 12.2.5 Case 4S.3: transfer P3 data + SW1 SW2. What did I missed ?

Comment: You're right in that the card probably *should* send as many bytes as indicated by P3. - But then, P3 cannot encode a length greater than 256, so what to do in the case of more data? I think the spec allows doing this via the ACK byte mechanism where the card should(?) continue to stream chunks of data out by itself, which yours doesn't :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: it was a **timing** issue.

The card **do have** a Status Word to send, however my process between the read operations was too long so by the time I requested it, it was no longer available in the card.

I should have highlighted that I was developing the reader part myself.

Answer (score -1):

In T=0 protocol it is not possible to have data more than 256 bytes.

In your case, it might be a bug (or misunderstanding) of the protocol of your app which after retrieving 256 bytes it still sends 61XX back.

Actually it is not clear in your log what is the Status Word of your GET RESPONSE command, and if it is 9000, then everything is fine and no more discussion. In this case if you repeat GET RESPONSE command you might get the latest data again!

Just to answer your specific questions:

> I can't found the part of the specification that allows the card to "skip" the status word

You can simply ignore it!

I mean if the card informs that it has some data available (61 XX) and you don't send any GET RESPONSE command but another command then the data will be lost.

> or how to deal with answers longer than 256 bytes. Any pointer ?

In protocol T=0 it is not possible. You better use protocols T=1 or T=15 instead.

Or you can somehow workaround it by a bit enhanced protocol and then you should rewrite the app to support it (if the app is yours) and it might be not standard anymore!

Comment: *Actually it is not clear in your log what is the Status Word of your GET RESPONSE command*: that's the whole point, I got **no** status word to my GET RESPONSE, only data and timeout. Issuing a new GET RESPONSE send the **following** data (not the same: I expect the applet to answer with more then 256). I only got a SW when whole the 256-blocks are sent by the card and it has Le < 256 to send.